# ConstraintLayout space between ImageView to ProgressBar

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to create `ConstraintLayout` with `ImageView` and `ProgressBar`(below the image view) :

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/loading_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000B4A">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:contentDescription="" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginTop="1250dp"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

When I implement it the `ProgressBar` is not below the `ImageView` and there is no space between them.

Any idea what is the problem?

Attached Photo:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the progress bar below the imageview you should use `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"` to align the top of the progressbar to the bottom of the imageview

```xml
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
android:id="@+id/loading_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000B4A">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:contentDescription="" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]